# Odoo Landingpage

Tags: web, odoo

How can i make a Landing page on Odoo Website with a big picture on it.

this isn't working. Thinks link "normal" CSS in HTML is working fine, by using style or body.

> Error: This page contains the following errors:error on line 26 at column 8: Opening and ending tag mismatch: meta line 0 and head Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

```html
        
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
            body, html {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
            }

            .bg {
                /* The image used */
                background-image: url("...");

                /* Full height */
                height: 100%; 

                /* Center and scale the image nicely */
                background-position: center;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-size: cover;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="bg"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you have non-valid xml in Odoo. I assume you have this code in Odoo view xml template. This template must be valid xml. Ýour code is html and html is not always valid xml because html does not have mandatory ending for meta tags. You can correct this by using self ending format of element in meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
```

Note the "/" before ">" in the end of the line.

I did not figure out in the example how you are serving the landing page from Odoo. Where do you have this page code? In Odoo website you normally would create a page and specify only the contents, not the whole html document.

I hope you can get your landing page working with this help. If you need more help, please provide more information about your use case.

Br,

Veikko

Comment: Its working! but i can't load the picture. Even if i use 'scr' or url.

 background-image: src="/web/image/website.s_big_picture_default_image" ;

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot help more based sololy on just the html source of your page. Please provide more detailed information on how you have implemented the page in Odoo, what url you are using to reach the page, what do you see when accessing page etc.

Comment: I tried almost everything, but it doesn't render the picture.Here is the code:
<t t-name="website.5">
  <t t-call="website.layout">
    <div id="wrap" class="oe_structure oe_empty">
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<style>
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}


    background-image: url(/web/image/website.s_cover_default_image);

    height: 100%; 

    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

Comment: Can i send you an e-mail? i don't how to Post the Code again in a commend. And thank you so much for helping!!

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet. Looks like you have a whole html document inside a div in view template. The browser does not understand html element inside div element. Where exactly do you have this cone in Odoo?

Comment: It's just on the landigpage. idk what else i should try

Comment: Do you mean with "landingpage" Odoo home page and other Odoo pages in website CMS module? If this is the case then I might have some glue how you could solve this. In this case please close this original question about xml validation error and create another question with this new question in title and your qweb template from your 13th day commend as code example.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But i found out that a Big Picture isn't possibly, because it will affect the footer and Header. I have now an even bigger problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50233547/unable-ssl-tls-on-odoo-website-builder 
perhaps you can help me an that one as good as you did here

Comment: When someone says it is impossible, doubt. I know that whole window images are possible with odoo. ;-) I could not have a clear picture about the bigger problem, please clarify it.

Comment: i know that there is a way, because you buy a solultion for 50 €. But with "normal" bootstrap skills - it looks impossible :(