# Unable SSL/TLS on Odoo Website Builder

Tags: web, odoo, builder

The only why to deploy my Odoo Website on my host, is by creating a Subdomain to get the CNAME over Odoo. Unfortunately, if i do that i can't use my free Top Level Domain from Strato. A Wildcard isn't possible as well. And because I use the Odoo Website, I can't access the .htacces file. 
Question: Does anyone see a way - how to protect my Website with an SSL certificate? can't see any Documentation from Odoo - only:
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/user/10.0/es/website/publish/domain_name.html

Comment: Please clarify your setup. Are you using Odoo on your own server or hosted on odoo.com? The document refers only to cases where you have your domain hosted in Odoo Online at odoo.com.

Comment: i am using the Odoo Website Builder. (SaaS)

Comment: There is no way to have custom domain with SSL cert for it in pure self-service Odoo Online. The documentation only refers to using external CDN with SSL certs. Some Odoo.com forum posts say that you can ask for this from Odoo support by email. You can try that. Another option is to have separate reverse proxy for your domain with ssl cert and route traffic to https://yourdomain.odoo.com from there. This will work but definitely is not the best option.